# Image picker bug when sharing screen

Tags: flutter, dart, imagepicker

I have noticed an error when showing the app to my client via "Zoom app". When sharing screen and taking photo, the app pops all the views to the current main route and the state of the app is restarted.

This only happen when sharing screen.